# Add some symbols to row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need add some symbols to existing row. Need to add 10 000 000

Example:

```
Values  NewValues
98       10000098
99       10000099
100      10000100
1000     10001000
```

Comment: Hint:  `UPDATE`.

Comment: are the values numeric?  It looks like you want to add numbers, not symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Simply [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) your table as:

```
UPDATE Talbe
SET Col = Col + 10000000;
```

For some rows, you should use `WHERE` clause to specify the rows you want to update it.

```
UPDATE Talbe
SET Col = Col + 10000000
WHERE Condition;
```

That if your column datatype is `INT`, otherwise you need to cast it.

Comment: Assuming the original table is numbers this is the easiest way to solve this.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah, it's just from copy/paste :)